# Optimal Control Problem with Fraction Objective

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimal-control

$\mu$ and $\lambda$ are two positive constants and $\mu > \lambda$. $c$ and $b$ are two positive constants and $c < b$. How to solve the following optimization problem?

\begin{align}
\max_{T\ge 0, H_t} & \, \frac{W_0}{M_0} \\
s.t. & \, \frac{dW_t}{dt} = \mu W_t - \mu H_t, H_t \ge W_t + c, W_T = 0. \\
     & \frac{dM_t}{dt} = \lambda M_t - \lambda H_t, H_t \ge M_t + b, M_T = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Have you tried Pontryagin's maximum principle? Namely, I think this problem would still fit into that formulation.

Answer (score 0):

Using a state space formulation with the state vector, $x_t$, as $\begin{bmatrix} W_t \\ M_t \end{bmatrix}$ and $H_t$ as the input, $u_t$,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{W_t} \\
\dot{M_t} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mu & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} W_t \\ M_t \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} -\mu \\ -\lambda \end{bmatrix} H_t \\
\dot{x}_t = Ax_t + Bu_t$$

Taking its Laplace transform,
$$sX(s) - x_0 = AX(s) + BU(s) \\
X(s)(sI - A) = BU(s) + x_0 \\
X(s) = (sI - A)^{-1}(BU(s) + x_0) \\
x_t = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[(sI-A)^{-1}(BU(s) + x_0)] \\
\begin{bmatrix} W_t \\ M_t \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} -\mu e^{\mu t}* H_t + e^{\mu t}W_0 \\ -\lambda e^{\lambda t}*H_t + e^{\lambda t}M_0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

A little algebra gives us
$$W_0 = (W_t  + \mu e^{\mu t} * H_t )e^{-\mu t}\\
M_0 = (M_t + \lambda e^{\lambda t} * H_t )e^{-\lambda t}
$$
Using $W_T = M_T = 0$, we get
$$W_0 = (\mu e^{\mu T} * H_T) e^{-\mu T} \\
M_0 = (\lambda e^{\lambda T} * H_T) e^{-\lambda T}$$

Since $e^{\mu T}, e^{\lambda T}$ and $H_T$ are constants for a particular $T$, their convolution w.r.t time yields $te^{\mu T}H_T $ and $te^{\lambda t}H_T $.
Therefore, the objective function becomes $\frac{W_0}{M_0} = \frac{\mu}{\lambda}$, which is independent of $T, H_t$.